# Subsetting data based on whether a variable is in a list

Tags: r, machine-learning, data-manipulation

I have some data on NFL player statistics. I want to separate it into training and test datasets where the split is based on the year of observation.

In particular, my data contains observations of player statistics from 1999 through 2019. I want to randomly select 20% of years (4 years) of data to serve as my test set and then have the remaining 17 years of data be my training set.

What I have now is:

```
# Set seed
set.seed(43)

# Determine how many years of data should be in test
split <- round(nrow(as.data.frame(table(data$year)))*0.20)

# Pick (split) random years to keep as test
test_years <- sample(data$year, split)
```

What I want to know how to write is:

```
train <- data where year is not in test_years
```

How would I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `%in%` to create a logical vector, then negate (`!`) to change TRUE/FALSE to FALSE/TRUE and subset the rows of the 'data'

```
train <- data[!data$year %in% test_years,]
```